# In CSS my side div between the header and footer (just for design) don't want to be 100% high. Also cannot get aside menu items same length

Tags: html, css, height, width, html-lists

I am making a website: http://arc-angyal.hu/

My first problem is, I cannot get the red div on the left side to be as high to fill the space between the header and the footer. It's placed right after the header and before the nav. I already set:

```css
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

and the div:

```html
< div style="background: rgb(204, 0, 0); min-height: 100%; 
      height: 100%; float: left; width: 10%;">< /div>
```

Clear is only set for the footer, to prevent the div from hanging into that.

My other problem is with the aside nav. I would like to get the list items yellowish background to be as long as the longest one's. I already tried several methods to get their width to 100% and other techniques for similar things I found on web.

I've been searching for the solution for both my problems, but I just could not find any that solved it. Any advices are welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the header and footer to float left and width 100% with `float:left;width:100%;`
and your sidebar element should be in between of header and footer and you can make it `clear:both;`

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you recommended, but I could not get it the way it should.
Here's a fiddle if you'd like to give me further help: https://jsfiddle.net/fj3fxqar/
If you do so, please tell me what should I change.